# What is Safari Safe Browsing Data and why does it need to copy every time I sync my iDevice?

Tags: itunes, windows, mobile-safari

Whenever syncing iDevices to iTunes, I always see "Safari Safe Browsing Data" being copied. This naturally sounds alarming. Is Apple tracking my browsing history‽

What exactly is it, and why does it need to copy every time?

Comment: Personally, "Safe Browsing Data" seems the opposite of alarming to me, but to each his own.

Answer (score 6):

[Google Safe Browsing Data Syncs to iOS Devices Via iTunes](http://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/google-safe-browsing-data-syncs-to-ios-devices-via-itunes/) explains what it is:

> This database, provided by Google, is used by mobile Safari to check for known malicious web sites. To check if this is activated on your iOS device, go to Settings > Safari, then look for the Fraud Warning slider. If it’s not set to “On,” do so; it’s a good way to protect your device and yourself from known malicious websites.

Comment: Why does it copy every time? Database update perhaps?

Comment: Yes, Google is constantly updating this database, so your iDevice refreshes on every sync.

Answer (score -2):

Go on your iPod to

SETTINGS > SAFARI > FRAUD WARNING and if it's turned on, turn it off. Then go to ADVANCED > WEBSITE DATA click edit, scroll to the bottom and click remove all website data. Turn FRAUD WARNING on again and you are ready to go.

Comment: Terrible advice to tell someone to turn off their fraud warning when all they are doing is asking for information.